# hollow square inside square patterns

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

This is what my program is doing: it takes `n` as input  and computes the Square side length using `2^{n+1}-1`,then it prints 'n' squares in the pattern that the vertex of each square is placed in the middle of the side of the previous square. Here are some sample outputs:

input: `2`

output:

```
#######
#..#..#
#.#.#.#
##...##
#.#.#.#
#..#..#
#######
```

input: `3`

output:

```
###############
#......#......#
#.....#.#.....#
#....#...#....#
#...#######...#
#..##.....##..#
#.#.#.....#.#.#
##..#.....#..##
#.#.#.....#.#.#
#..##.....##..#
#...#######...#
#....#...#....#
#.....#.#.....#
#......#......#
###############
```

I have tried to solve this problem for some time,the problem is that I can't make the code work like an algorithm for any given number,here is my code which works fine for only `n= 1 or 2` :

```
lenght = int(input('Please input an integer : '))
n=2**(lenght+1)-1
mid=int((n-1)/2)-1


print('#'*n)

i=-1
cnt1 = 0
midflag=1

while cnt1 < (n-2):
    print('#',end='')

    a='.'*(mid)+'#'
    if  lenght==1:
        a='.' 
    print (a,end='')
    print ('.'*(i),end='')

    if i==-1:
        print (a[::-1][1:],end='')
    else:
        print (a[::-1],end='')

    if midflag*mid>0:
        mid-=1
        i+=2
    else:
        mid+=1
        i-=2
        midflag=0

    cnt1 += 1

    print('#')

print('#'*n,end='')
```

Any advice on how to make it work for any given number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to make it work that way, but I find it easier to first create the grid in memory and then "draw" the shapes in that grid. That way you don't have to produce the final output line by line, having to take into account all shapes at the same time.

So I would propose to create a matrix that initially only has dots and no hashes. Then iterate the different shapes you have to draw (either square or diamond) and put the corresponding hashes at the right coordinates in that matrix.

Note that the output is symmetric both horizontally and vertically, so you could just focus on one quadrant of the matrix, and only at the end produce the other quadrants from that, just by mirroring that one quadrant along X and Y axis.

So here is code that takes that approach:

```
length = int(input('Please input an integer:'))
# let n be the half of the total width, including the centre file
n = 2**length 

# create an empty grid, just for the bottom-right quadrant
grid = [['.']*n for _ in range(n)]

# Draw each of the partial shapes in that quadrant
for shape in range(length):
    if shape % 2: # draw one side of a diamond
        for i in range(1, n):
            grid[i-1][n-1-i] = '#'
        n //= 2 # adjust the size for the next square (if any)
    else: # draw 2 half-sides of a square
        for i in range(n):
            grid[n-1][i] = '#' # horizontal side
        for line in grid[:n]:
            line[n-1] = '#'    # vertical side

# Create the other 3 quadrants by mirroring, and join to a string 
print("\n".join(["".join(line[:0:-1] + line) for line in grid[:0:-1] + grid]))
```